# how to fix "Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string" in laravel?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I'm having a problem with PHP returning Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string, when i added this lines of codes.

this is my controller

```
public function showMarks($id){
    $user = Auth::id();
    $quiz_id = $id;
    $score = DB::select('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`answer`))
                        FROM questions JOIN studentquiz
                        ON ? = studentquiz.user_id_std_quiz
                        WHERE questions.quiz_id = studentquiz.std_quiz_id
                        AND  questions.number = studentquiz.nomor_quiz
                        AND questions.answer = studentquiz.std_answer',[$user]);
    DB::insert('insert into scores (`quiz_id`,`std_id`,`scores`) values(?,?,?)',
    [$quiz_id,$user,$score]);
    return view('/marks');
}
```

this is in web.php

```
Route::get('/marksshow/{id}','quizController@showMarks');
```

anyone knows how to fix it?

Comment: welcome to SO ...you should put exact error what your getting or screen shot of error

Comment: Avoid using images for anything that's textual. Copy the entire error, together with the line that's causing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answer of DB is a object of stdClass, use this

```
$score = DB::select('SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(`answer`) as count ) ...
$score[0]->count
```